# Instrument of mass destruction?

Tags: word

```
Tenwrshtotpdn03yuy4w1esah
```

What mysterious word hides behind this weird sentence?

Comment: Any context that you can provide?

Comment: You only need to find a pattern and the answer will be clear, it doesn't really need a context

Comment: Hey, I don't mind getting downvotes but could you please explain why? SO I can improve for next short puzzles like these

Comment: Maybe it's because the riddle's vague. I didn't downvote but it's one of the reasons given in the arrow.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I assume whoever did did so because of http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: Okay, i'll try better for next time, I thought a little thinking with the title was enough, i'll put some flavour around next time :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you

> Take the first letter, then the last, then the second, then the second last, etc.

you get

> `Theanswer1swh4tyoutyp3d0n` (The answer is what you typed on)

so the word is

> keyboard

Comment: Wow, it was way faster than expected :) i'll accept when I can

Comment: The answer was up at the same time the question showed up, for me.

Comment: There was a 7 minute difference, sorry question_asker :(

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Is there a link with the title ?

Comment: Yeh, in the sense of the internet can now be a dangerous place, and lot of things can be achieved with a single of these.

Comment: I'm curious, now that it's been solved... how does the title relate to the question?